# How can I manually set an ID for an AUTOINCREMENT column using a designer-generated DataTable?

Tags: c#, ms-access, ado.net

I'm creating a database system in C# for a library system (using an Access database), and I've hit a brick wall. I've got a table called "BSUser" which has an auto-increment column for the primary key, "UserID"; I want this to be auto-generated if the user doesn't enter a value when defining a new User, but I also want it to be able to accept a manually-defined value. I'm using the following code to create my new row given the information entered by the user. Note the check to see whether the user ID is null...

```
BookshelfDataSet.BSUserRow user = dataSet.BSUser.NewBSUserRow();
if (userID != null) user.UserID = userID.Value;
user.Forename = forename;
user.Surname = surname;
user.IsAdmin = isAdmin;
dataSet.BSUser.AddBSUserRow(user);
SaveDataSetToDatabase();
```

Here's the code that should update the database...

```
private void SaveDataSetToDatabase()
{
    this.bookTableAdapter.Update(this.dataSet);
    this.copyTableAdapter.Update(this.dataSet);
    this.userTableAdapter.Update(this.dataSet);
    this.loanTableAdapter.Update(this.dataSet);
    this.ratingTableAdapter.Update(this.dataSet);
}
```

The row is successfully being saved to the database, but its ID is being automatically generated despite the fact that I've set it manually. This is a problem, as the existing users of the library will already have IDs from the old system, so I need to carry these over into the new system. Please could somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix the problem?

Comment: What purpose would this serve?

Comment: The users of the library each have a library card with a barcode on it; I therefore need to be able to type these barcodes in for the existing users to set them up on the new system.  There are also barcodes stuck on the existing books to uniquely identify them.  I want to have the corresponding columns as auto-increment though, so when new users or books .etc. are added to the database (that don't yet have a barcode), the system will be able to generate IDs and barcodes for the new objects.

Comment: Create a new Primary key on the table that is a GUID or string or Autoincrement. Create an index on the old Pkey field and you have the best of both worlds, an absolute unique id for each row and a unique id for the item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to either use an auto-incrementing value, or set it yourself.  There is no option to do both.

Comment: This kinda sucks; if I implement the database code manually (i.e. not using a DataSet), I can have the best of both worlds (an auto-increment column with a key that can be manually specified).  I guess this is one of the downfalls of using code that's been generated by a designer rather than code that's been hand-crafted!

Comment: ( cc: @Lee.J.Baxter ) re: *"There is no option to do both."* - Not really true, because (1) the Access Database Engine allows arbitrary values to be inserted in an AutoNumber column when a new row is added, and (2) an event-driven Data Macro can be used in place of an AutoNumber field (see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39534557/2144390) for details).

Comment: @GordThompson - I wasn't aware that this feature was in Access 2010.  Thanks for the info!  Lee J. Baxter, this looks like the way to go.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have Access so I've ended up hand-crafting the code to drive the database manually (including supplying an optional user ID when adding a new user). Thanks for the info though; I'll have to dabble with this in future projects! :-)

Comment: -1 When you want to use an explicit value then include the autonumber column in the insert statement, otherwise omit the autonumber column form the insert statement and let the engine auto-generate the value. This is plain SQL and doesn't require a 'Before Change data macro' thingamajig.

Answer (score 2):

For those using Access 2010 or later, the desired result can be achieved by using a Before Change data macro. For a sample table named [BSUser]:

[UserID] – Long Integer, Primary Key
[ExistingID] – Long Integer
[Forename] – Text(100)
[Surname] – Text(100)

and the Before Change data macro

[image: BeforeChange.png]

if we include an [ExistingID] value then it will be used as the [UserID] primary key (provided that it does not already exist in the table)

```cs
var ta = new Database1DataSetTableAdapters.BSUserTableAdapter();
ta.Insert(null, 3, "Gord", "Thompson");  // insert with ExistingID = 3
```

resulting in

```
UserID  ExistingID  Forename  Surname    
------  ----------  --------  -----------
     3           3  Gord      Thompson
```

and if we don't include an [ExistingID] value then the macro will assign one for us

```cs
var ta = new Database1DataSetTableAdapters.BSUserTableAdapter();
ta.Insert(null, null, "Nora", "Newuser");  // insert with ExistingID = null
```

like so

```
UserID  ExistingID  Forename  Surname    
------  ----------  --------  -----------
     3           3  Gord      Thompson   
  1000              Nora      Newuser
```